# How to overwrite expensive transaction?

Tags: transactions, pending-transactions

I accidentally did a expensive contract creation txn with 1.100$ as max txn fees but only 45Gwei and now i wan't to overwrite it.

> **Details:**
>
> - Max Txn Cost/Fee: 0.302488875 Ether ($1,119.21)
> - Gas Price: 0.000000045 Ether (45 Gwei)
> - Txn Type: 0 (Legacy)
> - Gas Limit: 6721975
> - Gas Used by Transaction: Pending
> - Max Fee Per Gas: 0 Ether (0 Ether)
> - Max Priority Fee Per Gas: 0 Ether (0 Ether)

Now when i want to send a simple transfer txn as a replacement (with MetaMask) it says my replacement txn is underpriced even though i send it with >100 Gwei as Gas Price.

Do i need to send a txn with 10% higher **Max Txn Cost/Fee** or 10% high **Gas Price**?

If i need to send a higher Max Txn Cost/Fee, can i simply set the Gas Limit high enough to exeed the 10% and make a simple transfer txn that only uses 21.000 Gas? (I don't want to waste all that money for gas)

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Making a simple transfer of 21000 gas with a 10% increase in gasPrice should be enough

Comment: Thanks man, It was a problem with metamask saying TXN is underpriced, but worked with Trust Wallet! :)